# conflict with two inserts on same http request using lastinsertid

Tags: php, sql, pdo

I have this code below in a news-create.php, where I have a form to choose title and content for my news.

I want also to create a image gallery for my news.

Everything is working fine, but I want to show a error message if some image that user choose for my gallery dont have jpg, gif or png format.

Im inserting on my news table first, and then If my insert return sucess, I verify if user choose any files `if($_FILES['gb']['tmp_name'])` and if yes, I will upload
this images to my folder and then I will insert this images on my gallery table where id of my gallery table is icual to my news last insert id.

But Im doing this on same http request, so even When I select a wrong format for my images, Im inserting my news, and Im getting my two messages at same time:

```
echo 'News inserted with sucess';

echo 'Send only JPG, PNG or GIF images';
```

Do you know some way to fix this?

**This is my code:**

First Im inserting my news on database like this:

```
$f['title'] = $_POST['title'];
....

$insNews = $pdo->prepare("INSERT INTO news (title,  content) VALUES (?, ?, ?)");
$insNews->bindParam(1,$f['title']); 
$insNews->bindParam(2,$f['content']);               
$insNews->execute();
$insNews = $pdo->lastInsertId();
```

And then Im getting my lastInsertId  to create a image gallery to my current news, so I need to associate id of my current news with my gallery table

And then, If my insert returns sucess I will do my multiple upload (if user choose images to upload), and I´ll insert selected images of current id in my gallery table:

```
if($insNews->rowCount() >=1){
    if($_FILES['gb']['tmp_name']){
        $count = count($_FILES['gb']['tmp_name']);
        $gb = $_FILES['gb'];
        $folder = '../galery/';
        $year = date('Y');
        $month = date('m');

        if(!file_exists($folder.$year)){
        mkdir($folder.$year,0755);
        }

        if(!file_exists($folder.$year.'/'.$month)){
        mkdir($folder.$year.'/'.$month,0755);
        }

        for($i=0;$i<=$count;$i++){

            $ext = substr($gb['name'][$i],-3);
            $name = $folder.$year.'/'.$month.'/'.$idlast.'-'.$i.time().'.'.$ext;
            $extPerm = array('image/jpeg', 'image/pjpeg', 'image/png', 'image/gif');
            if(in_array($gb['type'][$i],$extPerm)){
                uploadImage($gb['tmp_name'][$i], $name, '800', $folder);

                //and then I will do my insert into galery table here
                $insGal = $pdo->prepare("INSERT INTO gallery (img, id_news) VALUES (?, ?)");
                $insGal->bindParam(1,$name);
                $insGal->bindParam(2,$idlast);
            }
            else{
                echo 'Send only JPG, PNG or GIF images';                    
            }

        }

    }
echo 'News inserted with sucess';
}
```

Comment: Why couldn't you get both success on the news entry and failure on the image type? They're different things, one checked after the other. If you want to prevent the news article from being added if there's something wrong with the image, then you need to perform that check *first* before inserting the article (meaning check the types, not do the insert into `gallery`). However, if that means I have to retype the article because it's not re-presented to me on error, I would probably not like that.

Comment: Thanks for your answer Jared Farrish. But with method that you are saying I need to send two http requests. One to check if everything is alright with my images and other to insert on my news and gallery table. And I didnt want that!

Comment: No I'm not. (Although there are scripts out there to check the filetype with Javascript). Your question is also very unclear and confusing.